# Material ripple style background animation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4bz0spx/21/), but the animation works only if I click and hold.

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#circle {
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}
#parent:active #circle {
  background-size: 600px 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Would it be possible to make the animation to load when the page loads?
Just want some background load in animation similarly to Android Lollipop ripple / Firefox OS for TV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `animation` for the transition to start automatically.

Learn more about `animation` here:

1. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations
3. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

**Updated fiddle:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4bz0spx/35/)

**Snippet:**

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#circle {
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  /*transition: .3s ease-in;*/
  animation: example 1s ease-in infinite;
}
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-size: 0px 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 600px 600px;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as it should.